# How to display list of pdfs in the app

Tags: swift

Need a little help... I am writing an app which will hold all the pdf guidelines for my department.  I can open a pdf linked to a button, but is there a way to list all the pdfs without coding each one...?

Currently I am doing this:
import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let pdfTitle = "AFOI"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func AFOIOpen(_ sender: Any) {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: pdfTitle, withExtension: "pdf"){
        let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.loadRequest(urlRequest as URLRequest)
        let pdfVC = UIViewController()
            pdfVC.view.addSubview(webView)
            pdfVC.title = pdfTitle
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pdfVC, animated: true)     
        }}
```

---

But I want to be able to add a huge pile of pdfs to the app and it list them out and have a link to each one in the app without having to do each one manually... is there a way or shall I just get typing?!!

Many thanks everyone.
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have the URL of one PDF in your bundle, you have the URL of your *bundle*. Now you can cycle through everything in your bundle, looking for PDFs, and listing them.

An even cleaner solution is a folder reference. Now all the PDFs can be in a single folder in your bundle. You know that folder's name, so you can look inside it and list its contents.

Comment: oh I see! Thank you Matt - think I will go with folder reference.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.